# How can I convert this M-N mysql array in this other array in PHP? (examples inside)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, many-to-many

Well, is pretty common to get an array like this in relations M-N in mysql:

```
[0]
'book_id' => 1
'title' => 'title'
'author_id' => 1
'author_name' => 'name1'

[1]
'book_id' => 1
'title' => 'title'
'author_id' => 2
'author_name' => 'name2'
```

So, there is an elegant/easy way to convert this kind or arrays in something like this?

```
'book_id' => 1
'title' => 'title'
'authors' => array( 0 => array( 'author_id' => 1, 'author_name' => 'name1' ),
1 => array( 'author_id' => 2, 'author_name' => 'name2' ) )
```

I don't find any script or combinations of functions that made this... and is pretty common, maybe I have not searched correctly.. don't know how to call the  problem...

Any ideas or experiences?

Thanks :)

PS: I don't want to use GROUP BY + GROUP CONCACT in MySQL, I found that pretty ugly solution...

**EDIT:**
I'm working in something generic, not only to solve this specific problem..

Comment: sure, I'm trying something generic, to use it in any place... but I don't achieve :S

Answer (score 2):

I would do the JOIN in SQL and the post-process the results into a nested array in PHP code.

```
$bookkeys = array_flip(array("book_id", "title"));
$authorkeys = array_flip(array("author_id", "author_name"));

$stmt = $dbh->query("...");

$books = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if (!array_key_exists($row["book_id"], $books)) {
    $books[ $row["book_id"] ] = array_intersect_key($row, $bookkeys);
  }
  $books[ $row["book_id"] ]["authors"][] = array_intersect_key($row, $authorkeys);
}
```

If you want the final array to be an ordinal array instead of keyed by book_id, you can convert it:

```
$books = array_values($books);
```

Comment: Pretty interesting solution... I believe I can do something generic with array_flip and array_interect_key.. I'm gonna try it, I will post later if I was success.. thanks!

Comment: PHP has a lot of builtin functions that can do sophisticated work for you, and since they're written in C, they (usually) run faster than PHP code you may write to do the same work.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution for multiple sub-keys:

```
$rows = collapse_rows($rows, 'book_id', array(
        'author_id' => array('author_name'),
    ));

function collapse_rows($rows, $key, $subkeys){

    # make a map of all fields we don't perform a simple copy on
    $skip_fields = array();
    foreach ($subkeys as $k => $v){
        $skip_fields[$k] = 1;
        foreach ($v as $v2) $skip_fields[$v2] = 1;
    }

    # now build our output
    $out = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $row2 =& $out[$row[$key]];

        # simple fields first
        foreach ($row as $k => $v){
            if (!$skip_fields[$k])){
                $row2[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        # now subkeys
        foreach ($subkeys as $k => $v){
            $sub_row = array($k => $row[$k]);
            foreach ($v as $v2) $sub_row[$v2] = $row[$v2];
            $row2[$k][$sub_row[$k]] = $sub_row;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

This lets you pass the primary key and a hash of sub keys and fields to aggregate by.

Comment: Hi, yeah it works perfectly. So much foreach scare me a little.. But let me study your suggestion, is also pretty interesting. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a "solution" based in Bill Karwin suggestion:

```
$key    = 'authors';
$output = array();
if ( is_array( $elements ) )
{
    $all_keys           = array_keys( $elements[0] );
    $conflicted_keys    = call_user_func_array( 'array_diff_assoc', $elements );
    $conflicted_keys    = array_keys( $conflicted_keys );
    $good_keys          = array_diff( $all_keys, $conflicted_keys );

    $conflicted_keys_fliped     = array_flip( $conflicted_keys );
    $good_keys_fliped           = array_flip( $good_keys );

    foreach ( $elements as $row )
    {
        if ( !array_key_exists( $row[$good_keys[0]], $output ) ) {
            $output[ $row[$good_keys[0]] ]          = array_intersect_key($row, $good_keys_fliped);
        }
        $output[ $row[$good_keys[0]] ][ $key ][]    = array_intersect_key( $row, $conflicted_keys_fliped );
    }
}

$output     = array_values($output);
var_dump($output);
```

Don't know if is the most eficient/correct.. On other hand, this will not work if there are more than one type of conflict... patches will be good received :)

thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this would work:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $out[$row['book_id']]['book_id'] = $row['book_id'];
    $out[$row['book_id']]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $out[$row['book_id']]['authors'][$row['author_id']] = array(
        'author_id' => $row['author_id'],
        'author_name'   => $row['author_name'],
    );
}
```

Rows are keyed by book ID and then author ID so we only have one output row per book and then per author inside that row.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm working in something generic, to use it in any place..

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the funcion that finally I will use, it is based completly in the idea of Cal but trying to use native functions as said Bill Karvin:

```
protected function collapse_rows( $rows, $key, $subkeys ) {
if ( is_array( $rows ) )
{
    // make a map of all fields we don't perform a simple copy on
    $skip_fields = array();
    foreach( $subkeys as $sub ) {
        $skip_fields = array_merge( $skip_fields, array_reverse( $sub ) );
    }        
    $skip_fields = array_flip( $skip_fields );

    // now build our output
    $out = array();
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

        // simple fields first
        if ( !array_key_exists( $row[$key], $out ) ) {
            $out[ $row[$key] ]  = array_diff_key( $row, $skip_fields );
        }

        // now subkeys
        foreach ( $subkeys as $k => $v ) {
            $value      = array_intersect_key( $row, array_flip( $subkeys[$k] ) );
            if ( !empty( $value ) ) {
                $out[ $row[$key] ][ $k ][]  = $value;   
            }
        } 
    }

    return array_values( $out );
}
return $rows;
```

}

Once done, I don't think it has a too much good performance... I wonder how other people solve this kind of problems...

Whatever, thanks to both!